# Determining the values of $\lambda$ for which the matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm working on a homework problem and am a little stuck.  The question is:  Determine the values of $\lambda$  for which the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} \lambda &-1&0\\
-1&\lambda&-1\\
0&-1&\lambda\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
is invertible.

I looked around and one site suggested finding the determinant, which I did:  $|A| = \lambda^3$

What I don't understand is what I'm supposed to do next, now that I have the determinant.

Comment: Your determinant is not correct!

Comment: Yes!  Thank you... I looked up the Cramer's rule for 3x3 determinants and come up with the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key principle here is that a matrix is invertible if an only if its determinant is non-zero.

We apply this principle here as follows:

Set

$A(\lambda) = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda &-1 & 0 \\ -1 & \lambda & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & \lambda\end{bmatrix}; \tag{1}$

then we have

$\det A(\lambda) = \lambda^3 - 2\lambda; \tag{2}$

thus $\det A(\lambda) = 0$ precisely when

$0 = \lambda^3 - 2 \lambda = \lambda(\lambda^2 - 2); \tag{3}$

the roots of this equation are easily seen to be

$\lambda = 0, \pm \sqrt 2; \tag{4}$

$A(\lambda)$ is thus invertible for all other values of $\lambda$.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: It does make sense. Thank you.  I believe I went wrong when finding the determinant since you have a different value that I do.  I followed the formula of |A|=a(ei-fh) - b(di-fg) + c(dh-eg) where the matrix is A = \begin{bmatrix} a &b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i\end{bmatrix} .  So, |A|=\lambda((\lambda x\lambda) - (-1x-1)) - -1((-1x \lambda) - (-1x0)) + 0((-1x-1) - (\lambda x0))

Comment: I used what I call the "arrows rule"; do you know that one?  Does it sound familiar?

Comment: No, but I will look it up and see if I can understand it.  Thank you.

Comment: Your probably won't find it under that name; that's just what I call it; it's explained here:  http://www.purplemath.com/modules/determs2.htm

Comment: Anyway, you should get the same result either way, so perhaps if you re-checked your calculations . . . I tried it your way and got the same result $\lambda^3 - 2 \lambda$!

Comment: I really appreciate your quick responses!  I double-checked my work and still came up with the wrong answer but I found something called "Cramer's Rule" for 3x3 matrices and I was able to come up with the right answer.

Comment: Hey, glad to help out!  And thanks for the "acceptance"!  Just be careful with those determinant calculations, it's easy to get confused with all those terms floating around!  You'll get it, I'm sure!  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $A$ is invertible iff it has a non-zero determinant.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the determinant of this matrix is zero, then compute $\lambda$ that solves this equation. Then all $\lambda$ that don't solve this equation are what you are looking for.